# Clojure: fully qualified name of a function

Tags: namespaces, clojure

In Clojure, is there a more elegant way of finding the fully qualified name of a function (known to have meta info) than

```
(defn fully-qualified-name [fn]
  (let [fn-meta (meta fn )
        fn-ns (ns-name (:ns fn-meta))
        ]
    (str fn-ns "/" (:name fn-meta))))
```

A run-time solution is required. Read-time and compile-time solutions are welcome.

Comment: Does it have to be in a function (rather than at compile time in a macro or the REPL)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`(resolve 'foo)` returns the Var named "foo", with its fully-qualified name.

Answer (score 5):

how about syntax-quoting ? it does auto-qualification. use ` instead of '

```
user=> `(inc)
(clojure.core/inc)
user=> `(fn)
(clojure.core/fn)
```

Comment: Very elegant and useful at read-time.  (str `inc) would be equivalent of fully-qualified-name.  Any run-time solution?

Comment: what do you plan on doing with the result ?

Comment: Not all functions have a fully-qualified-names (anonymous functions have not as partial....). That's a strange thing to lookup dynamically.

Comment: @Nicolas I have modified the question to clarify that a solution for functions with fully qualified names is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

`type` gives a fully qualified name, regardless of meta info.

Answer (score 1):

The output of .toString could get you started:

```
user=> (.toString map)
"clojure.core$map@11af7bb"
```

Comment: also written (str map) to get the fully qualified name use (str `map)