# How to get the name of a parameter function in runtime?

Tags: clojure

Is there a convenient way to check the name of a function which is a parameter of another function? For example,

```
(defn foo [a-fun] ...)
```

how should one get the actual name of a-fun inside foo in runtime?

Comment: Why do you need it? What if I pass an anonymous one?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the name of a function, why not pass it as parameter ?
You can get the [fully qualified name of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761628/clojure-fully-qualified-name-of-a-function) by using [`resolve`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/resolve). Your code would then be called like that :

```
(defn foo [a-fun]
    ;; no need to do anything to get the name
)

(foo (resolve 'bar))
```

Comment: my case is about debug. i need to trace out which function does what.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to get the name of a function.  Why?  Because functions do not *have* names.  They might be *bound* to names in some instances, but even when you define a name for a function, the function itself does not have a name.

For example, if you run:

```
(macroexpand '(defn foo []))
```

You wil get:

```
(def foo (clojure.core/fn ([])))
```

As you can see, `defn` is merely a macro that creates an anonymous function and binds it to a name.